# Complex Numbers Proof: Multiplication

Tags: complex-analysis

Express the vague statement "the complex multiplying ∙ can be almost always reversed" in a mathematical rigorous way and give a rigorous proof.

We were given the hint: perhaps it is easier to not use the complex conjugation, and solve a linear system with two equations and two unknowns directly.

EDIT: Note the dot was in the middle of a square

Answer (score 0):

The vague statement can be reformulate as follows:

*For all complex numbers $c$ and $w\neq 0$, there exists a unique complex number $z$
such that*
$$
  wz = c. \qquad (1)
$$

Proof:
Let $c = a + \mathrm{i}b$, $w = u + \mathrm{i}v$ and $z = x + \mathrm{i} y$
with $a$, $b$, $u$, $v$, $x$, $y$ real numbers.
The equation $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
  (ux - vy) + \mathrm{i} (vx + uy) = a + \mathrm{i} b.
$$
Yet, two complex numbers are equal if and only if they have the same real part
and the same imaginary part, so $(1)$ is equivalent to the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{cases}
  ux - vy = a \\
  vx + uy = b.
\end{cases}
\qquad (2)
$$
It has a unique solution $(x,y)$ if and only if its determinant $u^2 + v^2$ is non zero. Noting that $u^2 + v^2 = \lvert w \rvert^2$, we see that
the equation $(1)$ has a unique solution $z$ if and only if $w\neq 0$.